# Change bind address on hug API

Tags: python, hug

Can anyone tell me how to change the bind-address on the hug API form 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, please I have been looking around the internet and the only thing I can find is how to change the port number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using hug cli you can do in shell:

```
hug -a app.py --host 192.168.0.10
```

or in the code at the end of your `app.py` (or whatever it's name is) file:

```
hug.API(__name__).http.serve(host="192.168.0.10")
```